# Access database is randomly not updating and the ASP.Net page is losing the changes

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

The required behavior should be ...

I have an asp.net page with a number of text boxes and an update button. When the asp:button (update button) is clicked my Access database is updated and a new page web page displayed which has been built from the data entered into the previous text boxes.

What's actually happening ...

Occasionally the button click (update) does not update the database and all data\changes are lost with the page returning to its original position. This behavior is unpredictable and random as to when it occurs. I can use the page to enter data and view the resulting page repeatedly and then for no reason the update fails and I lose the changes.

I have been trying to trace the behavior for some time. As it is not predictable, however, I can't seem to determine the cause. It's now driving me nuts!

If someone can provide some direction please, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please let us see some code so we can provide help.